# Kubernetes - How to deploy Filebeat on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, filebeat

I would like to know how I can deploy a basic Filebeat pod on Kubernetes?
I need to configure a `.yaml` file but I don't know what I need to specify:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: Filebeat
  labels:
    app: Filebeat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: filebeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: filebeat
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ???
          image: ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deploy the filebeat component with the [helm official chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/elastic/filebeat), is very easy deploy and maintain (upgrade, change configuration) the app.

Btw if you decide deploy with a custom yaml, the current version for filebeat docker image is the `8.0.0`, so your yaml example see like this:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: "filebeat"
      image: "docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check `filebeat-kubernetes.yaml` from
[https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat-kubernetes.yaml](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat-kubernetes.yaml#L45-L67), you will see there already prepared values for you

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: filebeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: filebeat
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.0.0
```